# How to test my java program?

Tags: java, email, testing, arraylist

I was asked to write this part of a program and then test it in the following way:

Add some statements to the main method that create two or three contact instances, add them to the address book, and then search for one or two of them. Display the result of each search to see if they were retrieved correctly. Then remove one of them and show the list to be sure that it was removed correctly.

I wasn't entirely sure how to test this. What should I write in the main class? Also, is the rest of the code correct?

**Do this for Contact Class:**

Create this class in the client package. This class should have three fields (An email address, A full name, A nick name). All of these should be Strings.

Provide two constructors: one full constructor (parameters for all three member variables), and one that has a parameter only for the email address. This second constructor will leave the other two fields null.

Add a toString method (and use the `@Override` annotation) that works like this:

```
Contact c1 = new Contact("jenny@gmail.com");
c2.toString() should return "jenny@gmail.com".

Contact c2 = new Contact("jenny@gmail.com", "Jennifer Abott", "jenny");
c2.toString() should return "Jennifer Abott (jenny) jenny@gmail.com".
```

**Do this for AddressBook Class:**

1. Create this class and have a single member variable of type `ArrayList<Contact>`. Define the variable, don't just declare it 
   You do not need a constructor.
2. Write an add method that has a Contact parameter and adds the contact to the contact list.
3. Write a remove method that has a String parameter, which is the nick name of the contact to remove. It returns nothing. Remove that contact from the contact list. Hint: Use the search method that you already wrote in order to find the contact, then remove that contact from the contact list. See the online documentation for ArrayList for how the remove method works in the ArrayList class. Be sure that the remove method does not crash if you give it a nick name that does not exist in the list.
4. Write a search method that has a String parameter, which is a nick name to search for. The method must iterate over the contact list. If the nick name is found (use .equals), return that contact. If no contact is found, return null.
5. Write a show method that displays each Contact instance. It has no parameters and returns nothing. Display one contact per line, and number each line. Like this:

   1. Jeff Meunier (jeff)
   2. Bill Gates (money)
   3. Vladimir Putin (vman)

   Make sure that the numbers shown start at 1, not at 0.

**Contact class:**

```
package client;

public class Contact 
{
  private String _emailAddress;
  private String _fullName;
  private String _nickName;

  public Contact(String emailAddress, String fullName, String nickName)
  {
    _emailAddress = emailAddress;
    _fullName = fullName;
    _nickName = nickName;
  }

  public Contact(String emailAddress)
  {
    _emailAddress = emailAddress; 
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    if(_fullName == null)
    {
        return "<" + _emailAddress + ">";
    }
    else
    {
    return _fullName + " " + "(" + _nickName + ")" + " " + "<" + _emailAddress + ">";
    }
  }
}
```

**Address Book class:**

```
package client;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddressBook 
{
  public ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

  public void add(Contact _contact)
  {
    contactList.add(_contact);
  }

  public Contact search(String nickName)
  {
    for (int n=0; n < contactList.size(); n++)
    {
        if(contactList.get(n).equals(nickName))
        {
            return contactList.get(n);
        }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void remove(String nickName)
  {
    if(search(nickName) != null)
    {
        contactList.remove(search(nickName));
    }
  }

  public void show()
  {
    for(int n=0; n<contactList.size(); n++)
    {
        System.out.println(n++ + ". " + contactList.get(n).toString());
    }
  }
}
```

I don't have much in the main class yet, but here it is:

**Main Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import client.Contact;


public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Contact c1 = new Contact("jeffm@engr.uconn.edu");

    Contact c2 = new Contact("jeffm@engr.uconn.edu", "Jeff Meunier", "jeff");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is demanded from you to do is inidividually connected with the main method. So you can share the class which contains it too. (:

Comment: I added my main class. There isn't very much in it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Add some statements to the main method that create two or three contact instances, add them to the address book, and then search for one or two of them. Display the result of each search to see if they were retrieved correctly. Then remove one of them and show the list to be sure that it was removed correctly."

If this is your task then:
1. You created a few contact instances, so this is done, but create a few more with all the available class fields set (this will be needed for the next steps)
2. Now you must create an instance of your address book class.

```
AddressBook addressBook = new AddressBook();
```

3. Add the created contacts to the adress book

   `addressBook.add(c1);`
   `addressBook.add(c2);`
   `// other contacts`
4. Use the show method to see if everything is correct.

   `addressBook.show();`
5. Try removing one and show the available contacts again to see if this worked.

   `addressBook.remove(c1.getNickName()); // Make get method for the nickname`
   `addressBook.show();`
6. Then search for a contact with a certain name, assign this to a new contact object and then print something from it to acknowledge that the object is the correct one.
   Here your logic can break, because your search does not cover the possibillity that you have more then one contacts with the same name. So you should return an List of found contacts instead of one contact. Implement this and search again (make sure you search for objects with unique and non-unique names so the testing is acceptable).

Your search testing will look something like this at the end:

```
List <Contact> contacts = addressBook.search("John");
for(Contact contact in contacts) {
     System.out.println(contact.toString());
}
```

Now since your delete method depends on the search, you will have to change it a bit too. When you do that, test the remove method again as above.

Work out every step until it works fine and your done.

P.S. You may want to print some description between different testing prints, so you can see clearly the results in the output